# Installed the monero gui client for windows. How do I join a pool to mine?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining

IS there a step by step tutorial on how to join a monero pool to cpu mine? I just installed the monero desktop client for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official monero client only supports solo mining as far as I know. You will need to download a different CPU miner for monero to connect to a pool. xmr-stak-cpu is a good one.
You can find that here: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu

I've always used linux for cpu-miners and compiled it from source. It looks like there is a windows .exe file hosted there, but you still might need to install a c++11 compiler.